# Meteor can't find template that is defined 4 lines later

Tags: meteor

This code:

```
//hello.js

import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';

import './hello.html';

Template.hello.onCreated(function helloOnCreated() {
 // counter starts at 0
 this.counter = new ReactiveVar(0);
});

Template.hello.helpers({
 counter() {
   return Template.instance().counter.get();
 },
});

Template.hello.events({
 'click button'(event, instance) {
   // increment the counter when button is clicked
   instance.counter.set(instance.counter.get() + 1);
 },
});
```

---

```
<!-- hello.html -->

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

  {{> hello}}
  {{> info}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <p>You've pressed the button {{counter}} times.</p>
</template>

<template name="info">
  <h2>Learn Meteor!</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://www.meteor.com/try" target="_blank">Do the Tutorial</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://guide.meteor.com" target="_blank">Follow the Guide</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://docs.meteor.com" target="_blank">Read the Docs</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://forums.meteor.com" target="_blank">Discussions</a></li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

Returns this error:

```
Error: No such template: hello
    at lookup.js:189
    at Blaze.View.<anonymous> (spacebars-runtime.js:32)
    at view.js:199
    at Function.Template._withTemplateInstanceFunc (template.js:465)
    at view.js:197
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (view.js:538)
    at viewAutorun (view.js:196)
    at Tracker.Computation._compute (tracker.js:311)
    at new Tracker.Computation (tracker.js:201)
    at Object.Tracker.autorun (tracker.js:576)
```

To prevent this for getting absurdly long, here is the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/tbirrell/chess-meteor) if needed.

In the [tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/templates) the template comes after the call. But for some reason, it won't on my page. If I move the templates above the call, it works, but not after. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the directory structure as requested. I've just started this project, and hello is the only page at the moment.

[image: directory[2]]

Comment: Might need to see your directory structure. Meteor has some rules about ordering client side imports.

Comment: @ilrein I added the directory structure. If there is any more info needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You should also add a comment to the top of each file which merely indicates the working directory.

I assume the first snippet of code is the contents of `hello.js` and the second snippet to be the content of `main.html`. I also assume that you are NOT showing us the contents of `hello.html`.

If all these are true, I can see that you are importing `hello.html` into `hello.js` BUT you are ALSO referencing `hello.html` WITHIN `main.html`. I assume your error is Meteor being confused as to which is the right reference, and grabbing the wrong one.

Clean code tends to separate Meteor templates into their own directories and files anyways. I'd get rid of them from main.html.

UPDATE:

I think your issue is in your main.js, or rather, your routing file.

For starters, it's bad JS practise to import in the middle of the code. Good practise is:

1) Import all absolute paths
2) Add a spacing
3) Import all relative paths
4) Never import after that

Take a good look @ `BlazeLayout.render` which you have added to your project, but haven't used. Attempting to just brazenly import the JS file is never going to work. You need to pass arguments to the render method, which include the template you desire to render.

Comment: They are both hello.html/js. Apologies for the confusion. Does this change your answer at all? Do you need to see my main.js as well?

Comment: Let me see both main.html/main.js.

Comment: Here you go.  https://github.com/tbirrell/chess-meteor/blob/master/client/main.js https://github.com/tbirrell/chess-meteor/blob/master/client/main.html